# How to end a nested loop?

Tags: python, nested-loops, nearest-neighbor

I wrote a script to perform a connectivity search in a binary image (the possible values for the array are 0 and 1). For each pixel, the code looks at how many neighbours have intensity 1, and if there are at least 5 neighbours with `I=1`, it assigns 1 as a value of the considered pixel. I want the code to repeat the process until no new pixels are assigned intensity 1. At present the code is not performing the connectivity search iteratively; do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

```
pixel_count = 0
pixel_counter = [0] * 100
for p in range(1, 100): 
    if p < 3:
       continue
    else:
        if pixel_counter[p-1] > pixel_counter[p-2]:
           continue
        else:
            break
        for q in range(1, ran_x-1):
            for r in range(1, ran_y-1):
                counter = 0
                if neighbours_mask_1[q,r] == 1:
                   counter = counter +1
                if neighbours_mask_2[q,r] == 1:
                   counter = counter +1
                if neighbours_mask_3[q,r] == 1:
                   counter = counter +1
                if neighbours_mask_4[q,r] == 1:
                   counter = counter +1
                if neighbours_mask_5[q,r] == 1:
                   counter = counter +1
                if neighbours_mask_6[q,r] == 1:
                   counter = counter +1
                if neighbours_mask_7[q,r] == 1:
                   counter = counter +1
                if neighbours_mask_8[q,r] == 1:
                   counter = counter +1    
                if counter > 5:
                   mask_1[q,r] = 1
                   pixel_count = pixel_count + 1
                   print pixel_count
                else:
                   mask_1[q,r] = 0
        pixel_counter[p] = pixel_count
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, is this correct?

"While the entire grid isn't filled with 1s, find the zeros and if they have 5 ones around them, set it to 1. Repeat til the entire grid is 1s."

Comment: My plan is: "While the entire grid isn't filled with 1s, find the zeros and if they have 5 ones around them, set it to 1. Repeat til no more 1s can be added."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This section of the code:

```
for p in range(1, 100):
    ...
        if pixel_counter[p-2] > pixel_counter[p-1]:
            continue
        else: 
            break
        ... dead code ...
```

will slurp all of the execution, the part where I've marked dead code, which contains your counters are never executed because they're unreachable.

I'm not quite sure what your trying to do there.

Comment: My idea was to repeat the "dead code" section `p` times, if the condition `if pixel_counter[p-2] > pixel_counter[p-1]` is satisfied...

Comment: then why did you put `continue` there? do you know what the `continue` keyword does?

Comment: Good point. That was a mistake. I will now correct the code - probably the error was connected with that

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title: the easiest way to exit a nested loop is to just move the loops into a function and `return` from that. E.g.

```
def f():
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            if i + j == 9: return
```